# How can I disable an anchor element in mustache file using YML configuration?

Tags: java, html, yaml, mustache, dropwizard

I have to disable a link in mustache file by getting value from YML configuration (in Dropwizard). If the value is disable, it should hide the element in the page so that user should not able to click the link. Is it possible to do this function?

Answer (score 3):

Mustache is logic-less, so you must provide a boolean value in your YAML file:

```
href: false
```

YAML also allows `off` and `no` as boolean values that map to `false`. You can then write a mustache file like this:

```
<a{{#href}} href="example.com"{{/href}}>
```

The Text inside `{{#href}}` … `{{/href}}` will only render if `href` exists and is not `false`. Note that you must set it to `true` for the tag to render.

Comment: I tried to implement this for a similar use case. In my attempt i am facing two issues, url is displayed as plain text and second in instances where href=null the hyperlink text is still displayed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74745046/issue-with-rendering-a-hyperlink-using-mustache?noredirect=1#comment131918311_74745046