# Issue with rendering a hyperlink using mustache

Tags: html, mustache

From what I can gather from [How can I disable an anchor element in mustache file using YML configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38238880/1264804) I should be able to have a link shown depending on whether the href attribute exists or not.

I have the following in my script,

```
 <a {{#href}} href= {{Link}} {{/href}}> url </a>
```

The issue i am having is that the word *url* appears as plain text i.e. without the link. *{{Link}}* holds a valid link.

**Edit**:

If i use the below script the hyperlink is rendered,

```
<a href={{Link}}> url2 </a>
```

But there are instances where *{{Link}}* would be null, in those instances i do not want *url2* to be displayed, which is why i am trying to use {{#href}} and {{/href}}.

What could i be missing ?

Comment: Maybe show us the rendered HTML in case I'm wrong about something.

Comment: @isherwood it is supposed to hide/show the url depending on the value of {{Link}}. I have attached the question where from i got the inspiration.

Comment: Ok. I'd still like to see the rendered output.

Comment: @isherwood *url* shows up without the hyperlink i am expecting it point to, just plain text

Comment: So you said. Why won't you show us the output? It's not a big ask.

Comment: Typo: You said the name of the variable is `Link` but before trying to render `Link` you are testing for `href` instead of testing for `Link`. (Do remember to provide a [mcve] in future, this would have been easier to spot if we'd seen the data you were putting into your template).

Comment: @Quentin that is not the case, the test is carried out using the {{#href}} and closing {/href}} tags. The variable that it is being tested for can technically be named anything.

Comment: @Bisoux — Then show us a [mcve] with the input data.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/nocodufoge/1/edit?html,console — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: not quite @Quentin, first the rendered link from your script is not exactly a hyperlink, granted the special characters could probably handled by applying *&*. I also removed *Link* from data, i still see *url* appearing, which should not be the case

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to inspiration from this post [How do I accomplish an if/else in mustache.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027525/how-do-i-accomplish-an-if-else-in-mustache-js) , an if/else (sort of) in mustache ([inverted sections](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#inverted-sections)) the below script works,

```
{{#Link}}
  <a href={{Link}}> url2 </a> 
{{/Link}} 
{{^Link}} 
{{/Link}}
```

which could be read as if *Link* has a non null value render the link otherwise do something else, in my case nothing.